# Best way, and how much time to allow, from Heathrow Airport to Waterloo Station?

Tags: trains, airports, london, lhr

And is Waterloo the right station for a train to Corbridge?

(They need to come into London first to do some on-arrival shopping and to store a bag they won't need until they get back to London, so I think that does mean finding a "central" station...)

Comment: For trains to Corbridge from London, [you need Kings Cross station, which has trains basically every 30 minutes in the day, 1 change](http://traintimes.org.uk/london/corbridge/11:00)

Comment: That does seem to answer my immediate questions. Thanks!